# Create child page template based off book parent page in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm still learning Drupal, but I'm completely stuck at this point. I need to create a template for the child pages based off the navigation link clicked.

This grid is a Bootstrap thumbnail grid serving as a navigation menu. I want to know how to create a template page based off the parent navigation menu item. Each page will have the same format based off this menu.

[image]

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as to what you are trying to accomplish. Since I don't really understand what you need here ...

Comment: The image displayed is a screen shot of a bootstrap thumbnail gallery that serves as a navigation menu. Each item is supposed to lead to their own child page, but those child pages share the same format across. I am supposed to create a template page for them, but really I dont know what to make. Would it be a view, node, etc. Also how am I supposed to name it? The documentation confused me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve, but as far as I can tell, you might need to start by trying to identify what those pages are and what parts they consist of (views, blocks/regions, nodes etc.) and then theme accordingly. Take a look at a diagram here https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/overview-of-theme-files to get a better idea of how this all works together.

Once you know what you're dealing with, look for customization options. It can be anything from theme settings to views configuration, working with css, blocks, custom page/node templates (see here https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/template-theme-hook-suggestions) etc.

If you need more info - please provide more detail, like links/screenshots of the pages that you need new templates for as well as explanation of how those 'templates' will need to look like

Answer (score 0):

So basically once you choose The book menu item "Topics", you arrive to the topics page with the navigation menu (shown in the screen shot above).

When you choose one of the images in the thumbnail gallery (first screen shot), you are supposed to arrive to the child page for that menu item chosen (sub book page). All the sub book pages (are supposed to have the same format displayed in this basic sketch screen shot displayed below).

So for that, I am required to make a template for these sub book pages. 
I just realized too that these sub pages would probably share the same parent of topic, so most likely, I have to create a template based off the action that "topics" = parent page ?

[Screen shot of sub child page for topic chosen/ sub book page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPgHp.png)

thank you for your patience guys!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after working with my new partner, we discussed trying to create a view that will have headers:

```
<h1>**Topic Overview**</h1>
[user content input under title] <br><br>
<h1>**News and Initiatives**</h1>
[user content input under title] <br><br>
<h1>**Resources**</h1>
[displayed depending on tag chosen to display]
```

We just cant figure out how do we keep these headers constant, but allow the content to change, or be changed for every sub nav item (child page from nav menu above).